# DIY 4*18650 Batteries charger with TP4056 paralel problem with how to balance it

Tags: battery-charging, charger, charging, diy, cell-balancing

days ago I did this project like the pic which is a DIY for 4*18650 OR 6*18650 (NOW I MADE 4 AND LET`S STICK TO IT) Sony vtc5a charger 3.7 v with new tp4056 with protection (copied from one youtube channel I don't own this pic) and please I want to do it **parallel like this, it already soldered**
[image]

**the problem**

is how to balance the four batteries because they must be balanced and the protection in the tp4056 is against the low voltage drop so when the voltage would drop the circuit will stop charging.
And really use already build charging balancer like IMAX6 and that would be totally dumped and would not consider as a solution because of the whole thing is a challenge between me and a friend of mine to DIY one of corse not from 0 to 100 but not already done.
 I'm thinking that if I soldered one PCB between the TP4056 for each battery (LIKE ONE OF THEY GUY HERE IN THE WEBSITE DID) but I don't know if that would work?????

((other questions))
How to protect them from overcharging if I used various batteries compasity???? 
[image]

Comment: Add circuit that you want to make. It is not very clear now.

Comment: Could u pls tell me what was not clear to u

Comment: What is the circuit you want to make is not clear to me. You posted 2 circuits you want to combine. What and HOW you want to connect between battery and TP4056? Add circuit to the question.

Comment: at the first thank for ur kind reply I made already the first one but then I noticed that the batteries are not balanced of course the voltage will be the same but the different compacity of each battery would make a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your configuration correctly, you already have charge balancing.

Normally, a single power supply is used to charge all of the cells that make up the battery. In that configuration, the charging circuit must monitor the condition of the individual cells and adjust the charging according to their individual charge state.

In your configuration, each cell has its own charge regulator. This is equivalent to charge balancing. The disadvantage to your configuration is that each cell charger must each have its own independent power supply or you must switch a single supply between them. You must exercise caution that you never power two or more charger circuits from the same power supply at the same time as this could lead to an explosion or fire.

Comment: yes I have one power supply with 5A every one of those would need 1A but for balancing I discovered that my batteries don't charge equally cz ones are older than the others so one charge quicker than may end with overcharging the battery ...so what comes to ma mind now is to  “equalise” the charge slowly via resistor to limit current, then hardwire it in once done. At that point, they’ll all charge/discharge exactly equally (eg, all cells at 3.942V).but the problem I don't have any clue where to put it could u help me by giving me a visual plan where to put the resistor connected to the all